19 int digit timestamp to date
I have a column consisting of 19 int digits and my goal is to extract the date out of it.
Almost tried all functions pasted online but I get an error every time, sometimes the error is "out of range"
Input Code : 1696832033213544000
-its in this format from the source database-
Required Format : YYYY-MM-DD
I'm using bigquery and I tried the following codes:
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP ("%Y-%m-%d", create_date)
SAFE.TIMESTAMP_MIcr(create_date)
DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE(create_date)
PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(create_date))

Well, to be able to decode this sort of time stamp, you need to know what it actually means ... And at least for us to be eventually be able to help you, you should show some of the values you are trying to decode

There is no such thing as google bigquery mysql. There is google bigquery and there is mysql. These two are two very different database products. Parse_date() function does not exists in mysql, so I must assume you use bigquery.

These are some of the values I'm trying to convert to date: "1696832033213544000" ,  "1696846924536816000" ,  "1697019825477760000"

@Shadow yes you're right, i'm using bigquery

Hi - please update your question with these example values and against each one give the value you want it to be translated to. Also please explain the logic that needs to be used to do the translation

You still haven’t explained what that input number actually represents. All we know is that it is a 19 digit number - you’ve provided no information as to how it can be converted into a date or if this is even possible

Looks like nanosecond unix timestamp.

@NickW the column represents when the record was created in the system - i don't have a lot of info but i know it represents timestamp of the record creation date

So the process to resolve your issue:

Determine your timestamp format. Not all interpreters/file formats can work with same format of timestamp. E.g. AVRO permits nanoseconds timestamp, while BQ permits max microseconds. If you are unsure - this website will give you some hint about what you're working with: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php
Timestamp is just integer that represents number of particular units since certain date (unlike timestamp starting date for timestamp is pretty consistent across programming languages). So - check documentation for dealing with timestamps for your stack. In your case that's relevant: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions
Truncate your integer to fit desired format and cast it to timestamp for your desired stack i.e. to go from nano-sec to micro-sec just divide by 1000

What you're after:
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MICROS(CAST(1696832033213544000/1000 AS INT64))

outputs:
2023-10-09 06:13:53.213544 UTC

